# Getting number of rows larger than MAX_INT from cursor in Python's psycopg2 with Amazon Redshift

Tags: python, psycopg2, amazon-redshift, integer-overflow

I have started using the Python module `psycopg2` recently to work with a [Redshift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) database.

I have a certain query which inserts a lot of rows (about 100 Billions), and the results of the cursor do not match:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT ...")
status_msg = cursor.statusmessage
row_count = cursor.rowcount
logging.info("status_message='%s', row_count=%d" % (status_msg, row_count))
```

Gives me:

```
>>> status_message='INSERT 0 100791203475', row_count=2006955667
```

For other big queries this also returns a negative number. I'm pretty sure this is because the number of rows is more than what can fit in an int, but I haven't found a way to fix it.

I tried experimenting a bit with Python's `int`s but it doesn't look like formatting here is the issue and more what is being returned by `psycopg2`:

```
>>> print "%d" % int(100791203475)
100791203475
```

Is there a way to make sure `psycopg2` will return the correct number of rows? Is this a bug in the `psycopg2` module like I'm starting to think, or am I doing something really wrong to end up with that result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in *Psycopg2* per se, so much as it is a limitation with the way `rowcount` is handled internally. *Psycopg2* is primarily implemented in *C* using *Python* extensions, and the type it uses for *rowcount* is (signed) `long`.

How big `long` is exactly is highly dependent on the environment in which it is compiled. Based on your results, I suspect it was compiled in a 32-bit environment, and therefore a long would be *-2^31+1 to 2^31-1*.

Here is the code on github where `rowcount` is defined: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/56adc590fffbc76fa5e99aa64c657621a630cbe1/psycopg/cursor_type.c

If you were so inclined you may be able to specifically compile it in a 64-bit environment so the `long` would be larger. See this link for installing from source:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source

I'm not sure how reliable something custom-compiled like that would prove to be, though.

My recommendation would be to use `rowcount` for informational purposes, but not for things which need ironclad accuracy. In addition to the overflow issues you have been experiencing for this case, according to the doc, there are other cases where -1 will be returned in non-failure cases. (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount)

Instead, to determine if the operation failed (i.e. malformed query or FK constraint violation, or similar), trap for exceptions. If there were no exceptions, then the operation didn't fail (although it could have updated/inserted/deleted 0 rows).